# dbt produce new schema instead of using the already existing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-schema

I'm using dbt core and I need to use my models on already existing schema. However when I'm trying to use one already existing It creates new schema, like schema name from profile + config model, in my case: `BRONZE_SILVER`.

profiles.yml:

```
dbt_snowflake:
  outputs:
    dev:
      ...
      schema: BRONZE
      ...

  target: dev
```

Config of my model.sql :

```
{{
    config(
        alias='DIM_TABLE',
        schema='SILVER',
    )
}}
```

What should I change in my config ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I need to create a macro to use custom schema, like explain by the [dbt doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas).

In macro folder, create macro `get_custom_schema.sql`  :

```
-- put this in macros/get_custom_schema.sql

{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {{ generate_schema_name_for_env(custom_schema_name, node) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```